# Border table row not working before adding td in IE11

Tags: html, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to make border around an HTML table and both `<tr>` before adding `<td>`. But the border is not working for either `<table>` or `<tr>`. This gives me a problem in Internet Explorer 11.

**HTML:**

```
<table style="width:500px;height:250px;outline:1px solid black;position:absolute;">
   <tr id="1" style='outline:thin solid black;'></tr>
   <tr id="2" style='outline:thin solid black;'></tr>
   <tr id="3" style='outline:thin solid black;'></tr>
   <tr id="4" style='outline:thin solid black;'></tr>
</table>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mcvadqf6/)**

Comment: Have you considered putting empty `td` tags inside the rows?  That renders with rows visible in IE:  http://jsfiddle.net/mcvadqf6/1/  If that doesn't solve the problem, I suggest you explain further.

Comment: That's Work for me. But not Recommend as i am adding td's dynamically to table. so i have given id's to that empty td's and remove afterwords. This increases one step further. But anyways thanks to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the there area number of rules associate with [various table elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#tables). Try using CSS to change the display type for table rows, perhaps by adding something like `tr { display: table-cell; }` to the CSS of your fiddle or (as @Surreal Dreams suggests above), adding content for the rows to display.

If you're trying to achieve some sort of formal, grid-like display area, you might do better using DIVs.  If you're after a fluid type of layout, consider Flexbox.

Hope this helps...
-- Lance